# In-App-Purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Is it necessary to have IOS paid applications contract in affect (Completed) in order to test In-App-Purchases in Sandbox environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. since you cannot setup a PAID app without signing the contracts.

Comment: Mine is a free app. So i I've IOS free applications contract in affect. But products which i wish to sell through my app are not free(paid).

Comment: Hence PAID .. You will be accepting money, so you need to sign the contracts before any testing takes place.

Comment: @Pranav  I am from India. What exactly i have to do sign these paid application contracts. Can you provide details for Tax related info.

Comment: @Pranav Can you help me from where do I need to sign the contract ?I have signed the contracts for iOS Paid Applications as well as iAds.Is there anything still missing ?

Comment: @Ajay Sharma In itunes Connect->contracts, tax & banking section, Your iOS paid applications contract shall be in "contracts in effect" section. Contact Info, Bank Info & tax info for the same shall be completed in order to test In-app in sanbox environment