# In-App Purchase returning 0 products and invalidProductIdentifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I was just checking and my:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
```

returned a SKProducstResponse with a products array size of 0. Why is this? If it can't find the product it should return a 0 right? I checked the product ID and it matches the one I have in my itunes connect. Checked the bundle identifier and it matches as well.. And yes, I tested this on a device

**UPDATE:**

I checked the

```
response.invalidProductIdentifier
```

and it returned the productID that I was trying to fetch. I went through this list:

```
• your app is InApp Purchases enabled? **yes**
• do you have an InApp Purchase test account? **yes**
• the product we offer is marked as "Cleared for Sale"? **yes**
• Did you upload the application to iTunes Connect? **no** (don't think it's necessary since 2011, correct me if I am wrong)
• do you generate and install a provisioning profile for the new "App ID"? **yes**
• Does your project is signed with the new provisioning profile? **yes**
• Are you compiling the project for IOS 3.0 or higher? **yes** 
• Are you using the full product ID when you make a SKProductRequest? ie for example: com.company.sampleapp.productid? **yes**
• Has it been several hours since you added the products to iTunes Connect? **yes**
• Does the contract payment application in the iTunes Connect is complete?  **just submitted it**
```

Should I actually have the paid contract in effect in order to have the IAP running?

Comment: Are you getting any response object or its a null? Hope this http://bit.ly/qifemx may help you.

Comment: I am getting a response object

Comment: did you wait long enough? sometimes it can take a few hours for new products to show up.

Comment: yes, checked my updated post above

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone StoreKit - invalid product id's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041656/iphone-storekit-invalid-product-ids)

Comment: I've followed that link you have, but got no results back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to your post:

> • Are you using the full product ID when you make a SKProductRequest?
>   ie for example: com.company.sampleapp.productid? **yes**

Actually you need to specify exactly the string (productId) you entered in iTunes Connect as the In-App purchase item. So if you specified `productId`, your SKProductRequest needs to have exactly that string set (without any *com.a.b.*). If you have specified in iTunes something like `com.a.b.item` (which is recommended), that is what you need to set in full in your Product Request.

**EDIT**
The post [In-App-Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799833/in-app-purchase) points out, that the paid applications contract must be in effect to allow in app purchases. So it might be cause for your issue.

Comment: The contract must be in effect as posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799833/in-app-purchase

Comment: thank you this was my problem. I assumed that itunesconnect adds the com.a.b for you. You're product id is exactly what you see in the product list.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and resolve it by following:

1. Go to iTunes connect > Agreements, Tax, and Banking
2. Check the "***Paid Applications***" contract
3. I have set up *Contact Info*, *Bank Info*, *Tax Info*
4. After filling the above detail, Contract status changed to *"Pending"*
5. It will take around 30 minutes to change contract status to be ready

That's it. now I will get the product list from the following delegate.

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse)
```

**Note:** Before complete above steps, I can see my product id in SKProductsResponse.invalidProductIdentifiers list in above delegate method.